# EEA Family permit renewal

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-spouses

My husband is from an EEA qualifying country and I am not an EEA national. I have travelled to the UK before through the EEA family permit. We live in the USA and are planning to travel to the UK for a vacation, but my EEA family permit has expired.
Can I apply for a new EEA family permit?

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, you can](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/apply).

You may know, however, that the UK is preparing to leave the EU.  Depending on whether there is a deal governing its departure, the exact moment when the free movement directive will cease to apply could be anywhere from 11 PM (London time) on <strike>March 29</strike> October 31st to the 30th of June, 2021.  If you need a visa to enter the UK, you will probably need a standard visitor visa at that point.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, You can.** It is possible until 30 June 2021.  You can also ask for standard visitor visa as the UK left the EU on 31 January 2020.